# Provide Data from GraphQL to Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, redux, react-apollo

I have project, where I use `redux`, `react-apollo` and I wonder, is any chance to provide data from `react-apollo` to `redux` through reducer. Pseudo code below.

```js
...
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const query = gql`
{
  ...
}`

/* Function, which I want to returns data from graphql */
const getDate = () => {
  return graphql(query)
}


/*---- Reducer ----*/
export default (state = getDate(), action) => {
  console.log(state) // function, instead data
  ...
}
```

Comment: yeah it's doable by dispatching events in `props` function of the `gql` config object. it's a little weird but that's the only spot really where you can hook into it. or for that matter, the target component's lifecycle event. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Apollo Link Redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-redux) might help. It's intended to provide backwards compatibility for Apollo Client v1.0 apps looking to migrate to v2.0. In short it will dispatch the following actions

```
APOLLO_QUERY_INIT
APOLLO_QUERY_RESULT
APOLLO_MUTATION_INIT
APOLLO_MUTATION_RESULT
```

which you can handle in your reducers.